# How to show subset of $\mathbb R$ is not an element of $\mathbb R$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How do you show that for some $A\subset \mathbb R$, $A\not \in \mathbb R$.

Intuitively it makes sense, but how do you actually prove it?

Comment: Which definition of $\Bbb R$ are you using?

Comment: So you want a proof that *there exists* $A\subset\mathbb R$ such that $A\not\in\mathbb R$? Is that correct?

Comment: You can probably define a set isomorphic to "common" $\mathbb R$ where $x$ is associated to $(-\infty,x]$. In this new set some subsets are also elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prove that *none* of the subsets $A\subset\mathbb R$ are contained in $\mathbb R$ as elements, one needs to craft the proof tailored to the particular definition of $\mathbb R$. For some definitions of $\mathbb R$ it may be impossible. For example, if you accept that $0\in\mathbb N\subset\mathbb R$ and if you accept the set-theoretic definition of zero ($0:=\emptyset$), then $\emptyset$ is both an element and a subset of $\mathbb R$.

However, it is possible to prove that *at least one* subset $A\subset\mathbb R$ is not an element of $\mathbb R$. A well-known consequence of the *axiom of regularity* is that [*no set is an element of itself*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity#No_set_is_an_element_of_itself). Let $A:=\mathbb R$. As $A\subset\mathbb R$, if every subset of $\mathbb R$ also belonged to $\mathbb R$, we would have $A=\mathbb R\in\mathbb R$ - contradicting the axiom of regularity.

Without use of the axiom of regularity, you can still mount a proof which would use something like Cantor's diagonal argument. Let $X=\{A\subset\mathbb R\mid A\not\in A\}$. If every subset of $\mathbb R$ is an element of $\mathbb R$, then $X\subset\mathbb R$. Now, try to answer the question: *does $X\in X$*? (You will conclude that $X\in X\iff X\not\in X$ - a contradiction.)

Answer (score 1):

It depends upon how the real numbers are defined.  For example, if a real number is an equivalence class of Cauchy sequences of rational numbers, then a set of real numbers is not a real number, because its elements are not equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences, but sets of such equivalence classes.